# PHP/jQuery - getting html tag <title>xxx</title> content

Tags: php, jquery

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>SOMETITLE</title>
</head>

<body>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $url ?>&t=XXX">click</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to use php/jQuery to get the content under `<title></title>` and place it to XXX at `<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $url ?>&t=XXX">`, how to do it?

Updated 2

```
<?php

$url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

?>

<div id="language">
 <ul>
  <li class="last">
   <span><a id="block-header-facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $url ?>&t=link"><img src="/home/images/icon/facebook.jpg" /></a></span><span><a href="#"><img src="/home/images/icon/twitter.jpg" /></a></span></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<script>
$('#block-header-facebook').attr('href').replace("link", "hi");
</script>
```

Thanks you

Comment: what do you mean when you say,  "I want to include the content of html title tag to XXX"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery (just change the selector $("a") to be more specific, using an id or a class):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>SOMETITLE</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 
    $("a").each(function() { 
        $(this).attr("href", 
             $(this).attr("href").replace("XXX", $("html head title").text())
        ); 
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $url ?>&t=XXX">click</a>
</body>
</html>
```

For the Update 2, change the script element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#block-header-facebook').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace("link", document.title));
});
</script>
```

By the way I do too recommend using the Ralph's server approach (use this only if you need to do it on the client).

**Added Recommendation (See Ralph comment)**

Change the a-tag and script to:

```
<a id="block-header-facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $url ?>">

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#block-header-facebook').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + "&amp;t=" + escape(document.title));
});
</script>
```

Less error-prone code, and I will work the same.

Comment: Your code works, but I change to my code, it's not work, please see my updated 2

Comment: ok, your code works, thanks so much. Could you advise what is the meaning by using each()?

Comment: Ok, all $("..") selectors return a collection of items, by using .each(function() { .. } ), you put some logic to each element in the collection and you access the item with $(this), tough you not strictly needed here (since it will return only one element) I use it also to not repeat the $('#block-header-facebook') selector. See documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: I appreciate the recommendation Alex, but I'm not sure I can say the same of yours. The text "link" could appear anywhere in that URL... what if the URL was something like `fb.com/linker.php?whatever&t=link` ? You'd get `fb.com/SOMETITLEer.php?whatever&t=SOMETITLE`, not to mention the title isn't properly encoded. Relying on a magical hard-coded string like "link" or "XXX" is never a good idea. Store it in a Javascript variable and urlencode it, otherwise you'll run into problems with this script sooner or later.

Comment: @Ralph, Agreed and I think of it since the replacement of XXX, but forgot to mention it (was rushing testing the code :-S), will edit the answer.

Comment: By "it" I mean the title tag. Not "the magic string". There should be no magic string. Build the entire URL in JS, no replace!

Answer (score 0):

there is a simple function that you can use at this page

http://www.phpro.org/examples/Get-Text-Between-Tags.html

Answer (score 0):

Or with JavaScript:

```
var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href;
link = link.replace(/&t=.+$/, "&t=" + document.title);
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href = link;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $title = 'SOMETITLE';
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?php echo $title ?></title>
</head>

<body>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $url,'&t=',urlencode($title); ?>">click</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I think it's always preferable to do it server-side if you can. Less computation for the client, less JS dependency/cross-browser issues, and no "lag time".

Urlencoding isn't necessary in this example, but it will be if your title has spaces and other weird characters in it.

Comment: I am using drupal to display content to user, so the page title is different in different page, so I can't hardcode title. thanks

Comment: No one said anything about hard-coding. That `$title` var could be stored anywhere, in a DB even. The layout file just has to read it. But if you want the easy route, then go ahead and use jQuery.